# Living in Minicrypt, but sampling hard instances without the solution

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, cryptography

In Impagliazzo's worlds, Minicrypt is the one, where one way functions exist.
In other words, we can sample hard-on-average instances of NP complete problems.

**Question:**
Is living in Minicrypt, where we can efficiently sample hard problems along with their solutions, equivalent to a Minicrypt, where we can efficiently sample hard problems without knowing their solution?